# Cannot find control with name: 'create_param[0]' angular

Tags: angular

I am getting `Cannot find control with name: 'create_param[0]'` in angular when I am clicking on checkbox which is dynamically created onload. Below is what code I am using:

**exercise-create.ts**

```
{
   this.exerciseForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      exerciseName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]],
      exerciseDescription: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(1024)]],
      difficulty: ['', Validators.required],
      all_params: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
   });
}

createItem(){
   return this.formBuilder.group({
      param: [''],
   })
}
```

**exercise-create.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="exerciseForm" class="col-sm-12" #createExerciseForm>
    <div class="field-block" *ngFor="let param of exercise.Params; let id = index;">
    <input type="text" formControlName="create_param[{{id}}]" 
      />
    </div>
</form>
```

**checkbox creation**

```
<div *ngFor="let param of customParams">
    <input id="{{param.param}}" type="checkbox" [checked]="param.isActive" (change)="updateActiveExercises(param)"/>
</div>

updateActiveExercises(param: any) {
  param.isActive = !param.isActive;
  this.dirty = true;

  let found = false;
  const newParams = this.exercise.Params.map((p) => {
    found = found || p.param === param.param;
    return p.param !== param.param || param.isActive ? p : null;
  }).filter(a => a);

  if (!found && param.isActive) {
    newParams.push(param);
  }
  this.exercise.Params = newParams;
}
```

**Note:** I want to add control on elements created onload and want to get their values.

Can anyone please help with the above?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add create_param in form group exerciseForm.

```
   this.exerciseForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      exerciseName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]],
      exerciseDescription: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(1024)]],
      difficulty: ['', Validators.required],
      all_params: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()]),
      create_param: [value]
   });
```

Comment: Hi, I have multiple values that's why I took it as an array. Can you please let me know how can I use it as an array please?

Comment: rafi, Actually I found all examples related to add new control to input fields by clicking on a button. But in my projects, input boxes are creating onload of page and I have to add control on that.

Comment: That article you shared is not helpful for me at  all. I want to add control on elements created onload and want to get their values.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `formArray` inside `formGroup`, and you cannot treat controls inside `formArray` like an element inside an ordinary array.

```
<form [formGroup]="exerciseForm" class="col-sm-12" #createExerciseForm>
    <div formArrayName="all_params"> 
        <div class="field-block" *ngFor="let form of all_params.controls; let id = index;" [formGroupName]="id">
            <input type="text" formControlName="param"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

- Each `formArray` should be treated as `formControl` insdie main `formGroup`.
- You will loop through `formArray` with `*ngFor` and each item should be treated as `formGroup`.
- After that; you can reach nested controls of each `formArray`.

Check this [Article](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/) about form Arrays in **Angular**.

**FOLLOWING:**

- Reach your params using formArray params like:

  `get params(): FormArray {
      return this.exerciseForm.controls.all_params
  }`

So, wherever you want get params, don't get it from `this.exercise.Params`, call it from previous getter like: `this.params`.

- Convert `exercise.Params` into `formArray` `onInit`, and get `params.value` on save.
- You cannot looping through original array and trying to link them with `fromGroup`, What's inside `<div .... [formGroupName]="id"> </div>` in the above code represents your control, like:

  `<div class="field-block" *ngFor="let form of all_params.controls; let id = index;" [formGroupName]="id">
      <input formControlName="param" type="checkbox" [checked]="param.value.isActive" (change)="updateActiveExercises(param.value)"/>
  </div>`

Comment: Hi, I want to add controls on elements created onload not onclick. Can you please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: Check my following answer

Comment: Sir, I don't want to add checkboxes onclick. It's automatically adding onload. I just want to add form control on them so that I can get their value.

If you want me to show you the code then please let me know.

Comment: Check the updated answer, and please take each note into consideration.